# Are Ethereum block numbers consecutive from genesis 0 ... Latest?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

If I use `w3.eth.getBlock('latest').number` to get the latest block_number, will 0 ... block_number include the entire universe of Ethereum blocks? [This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/how-to-get-transactions-by-account-using-web3-js) seems to suggest this is the way to get a wallet's transaction history.

```py
results = {}        
block_latest = w3.eth.getBlock('latest').number
for block_item in range(0,int(block_latest)):
    # check each block for matching transactions
    # and return them in result
    results[block] = result
```

Comment: block_number at time of writing is 11,273,759

Comment: https://etherscan.io/block/0 shows that there is a block 0.  But yeah, with 11million of them, this isn't the way you want to get them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, block numbers are consecutive on the Ethereum blockchain. To get a wallets history without libraries or APIs you would have to loop through every block but a better alternative (as Frank said in comments) is to use the [Etherscan API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts). The API call will probably look like:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api
   ?module=account
   &action=txlist
   &address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a
   &startblock=0
   &endblock=99999999
   &page=1
   &offset=10
   &sort=asc
   &apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```